# Python Naked Module WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

Been trying to test out a certain Naked module got from [here](http://sweetme.at/2014/02/17/a-simple-approach-to-execute-a-node.js-script-from-python/)  Cant get test file to after changing the format and even having the py and js file in the same directory.

```
 from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js
 success = execute_js('script.js')
```

Ive also tried C:\ez\script.js, C:\ez\script.js , C://ez//script.js and C:/ez/script.js and still get

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/ez/ked.py", line 3, in <module>
  success = execute_js('script.js')
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Naked\toolshed\shell.py", line 165, in execute_js
 raise e
 WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```